# Praying Zuhr instead of Friday Prayer

Tags: jumuah

During Friday, I replace the Jummah with Zuhr prayer during this pandemic. Mosques are open but I do not want to go outside because the situation is still bad in my country. So I pray 4 rakats of Zuhr at home every Friday. Am I sinful for this? And is it applicable that I leave the fold of Islam due to intentionally missing Jummah even if I pray Zuhr?

Answer (score -1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. So the **first part** we will need to establish is that is there anything in the Quraan or ahadith that talk about pandemics, plagues, etc. Here are some ahadith that talk about the plague.

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If you hear of an outbreak of **plague** in a land, do not enter it; but if the plague breaks out in a place while you are in it, do not leave that place." (Bukhari in the chapter called medicine).

> (the wife of the Prophet) that she asked ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ) about plague, and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) informed her saying, "**Plague was a punishment which ALLAAH used to send on whom He wished, but ALLAAH made it a blessing for the believers.** None (among the believers) remains patient in a land in which plague has broken out and considers that nothing will befall him except what ALLAAH has ordained for him, but that ALLAAH will grant him a reward similar to that of a martyr." (Bukhari in the chapter of medicine)

> ALLAAH Messenger (ﷺ) said, "**Plague was a means of torture sent on a group of Israelis (or on some people before you).** So if you hear of its spread in a land, don't approach it, and if a plague should appear in a land where you are present, then don't leave that land in order to run away from it (i.e. plague). (Bukhari in the chapter called Prophets)

The **second part** now comes to define what is a plague. We see in Merriam-Webster Dictionary that a plague is:

> an epidemic disease causing a high rate of mortality

The **third part** should be viewed if there are any exceptions. In which there is in the case of the masjid is destroyed, or inaccessible or having people pray would be a huge hardship. In your case if there is evidence that covid truly could harm you while praying in the mosque with all precautions (mask, social distancing, etc.) then there could be allowance given to the person to pray at home.

> The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, used to order the caller to say on a cold, rainy night, “Surely, pray in your homes.” (Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 635, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 697)

**First Question Answer** 
To arrive at an answer we need to see if covid fits the definition of a plague. When looking at the ahadith and the definition it would not be considered a plague. So with that being said it is still compulsory to go the masjid for jummah prayers (if you are worried you can always wear a mask and sanitize properly) and if the masjid is very far away then to create your own group to do the khutbah and jummah prayer. Of course as long as there is no fear for your safety and health by praying at the mosque.

**Second Question Answer** 
For your second question it depends that if it was done out of negligence or not.

> the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "Whoever missed three jumu'ahs out of negligence, ALLAAH will place a seal over his heart." (Nasai, in the The Book of Jumu'ah)

> ‘Abdallah b. ‘Amr reported the Prophet as saying, “The Friday prayer is obligatory on him who hears the call.” (Abu Dawud in the chapter called prayer)

In your case it seems that you were worried for your safety. However, now you have proofs and will need to go from now on.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If anyone downvotes my answer, please be courteous and say why it was downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Comment: i believe the answer could be much improved if you could have mentioned what the scholars have said regarding this matter. just quoting ahadith and quran tends to give the notion that one is trying to derive a ruling. its always best to refer to the learned scholars of our deen and include their argumentation when providing a good answer. as you have said before, some ahadith are self-explanatory but not always, as it needs a more comprehensive understanding to really know what scenarios are applicable to such rulings. this is just my humble opinion , jazaakallah.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum @ahmadnazeem, I hope you are doing well. I always try to give answers according to my understanding using the Quraanic ayats and ahadith on the subject matter. But I can add at the end of each of my answers that this is my opinion. Because then there is no purpose of this website because there are others that give answers according to scholars such as Islamqa.info and Islamqa.org, etc. Also on the help page it says: "It is important to judge the evidences provided by each answer to the best of your own abilities, and accept such answers at your own risk."

Wa iyyak.

Comment: @ahmadnazeem I wanted to say jazakaALLAH khairan to you as I edited my answer to provide more details. Also i appreciated you saying these words "just my humble opinion". keep up the good work.

Comment: Just because covid is not a plague this doesn't mean that it is not an epidemic or pandemic and a reason for not gathering people. The logic "covid" is not a plague means you must go to the mosque doesn't work here. Secondly there are enough ahadith which say that one shouldn't harm people in a mosque, and the qur'an says don't harm yourself nor even put yourself to harm, so it is legally permissible to avoid going to a mosque if there's a fear of getting infected. Imam a Shafi'i even said if a debtor fears meeting his creditor he can skip jumuah,

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum @Medi1Saif, I hope you are doing well. Ramadan Mubarak. I believe you missed reading what I mentioned in my First Question Answer : "Of course as long as there is no fear for your safety and health by praying at the mosque."  Furthermore, of course if you know you have the disease and are coughing and spreading (touching and hugging) then that would be wrong. However, precautions (masks , distancing) are implemented and people who are infected should stay home. Which did occur here in the United States. In the US people still travelled for work , went grocery shopping, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Friday Prayer (Salat al-Jumu'ah) is an important congregational prayer that is obligatory for adult Muslim men who are not traveling or sick. Friday Prayer is held during the time of Zuhr prayer, and it consists of a sermon (khutbah) followed by a congregational prayer.

It is not permissible for a Muslim to skip Friday Prayer and pray only Zuhr prayer instead, as Friday Prayer is a separate and distinct obligation that cannot be substituted with any other prayer. The Quran states, "O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for the prayer on the day of Jumu'ah [Friday], then proceed to the remembrance of Allah and leave trade. That is better for you, if you only knew" (surah Al-Jumu'ah, verse 9).

Missing Friday Prayer without a valid excuse is considered a sin in Islam, and one should make an effort to attend the congregational prayer whenever possible. However, if someone has a valid excuse such as illness, travel, or work that prevents them from attending Friday Prayer, they are excused and may pray Zuhr prayer instead.

In summary, Friday Prayer is a separate and obligatory prayer in Islam that cannot be substituted with any other prayer, including Zuhr prayer. It is important for Muslims to make an effort to attend Friday Prayer whenever possible, unless they have a valid excuse.